# Angular 1.5.8 component works different with typescript (ecma6) and (ecma5) configs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I'm using angularjs 1.5.8 with TypeScript 2.0.6.
Consider following tsconfig.json and angular component:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

and component:

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);
class testComponent {
    public message: string = "worked!";
}
app.component('ctrl', {
    bindings: {
        message: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>Hello {{vm.message}}</div>',
    controller: testComponent,
    controllerAs: "vm"
});
```

It's working fine, until I change target to "es6", and it doesn't work as expected and I achieve two different results without changing my codes.
Within es6 the "message" property will be null.

The following code works with both configs:

```
app.component('ctrl', {
    bindings: {
        message: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>Hello {{vm.message}}</div>',
    controller: function () {
        this.message = 'test';
    },
    controllerAs: "vm"
});
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Can you show us how the transpiled code look like? Also, how you've come up with the conclusion that message is null? How can we reproduce that?

Comment: `var app = angular.module('app', []);
    class testComponent {
        constructor() {
            this.message = "worked!";
        }
    }
    app.component('ctrl', {
        bindings: {
            message: '<'
        },
        template: '<div>Hello {{vm.message}}</div>',
        controller: testComponent,
        controllerAs: "vm"
    });
    //# sourceMappingURL=component.js.map
`
it's transpiled code that tsc generated automatically using es6 target and I really surprised why it doesn't work!

Comment: `var app = angular.module('app', []);
var testComponent = (function () {
    function testComponent() {
        this.message = "worked!";
    }
    return testComponent;
}());
app.component('ctrl', {
    bindings: {
        message: '<'
    },
    template: '<div>Hello {{vm.message}}</div>',
    controller: testComponent,
    controllerAs: "vm"
});
//# sourceMappingURL=component.js.map`
but using es5 everything work's fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, when instantiating the directive controller using a constructor function, Angular used to pre-assign the directive bindings on the controller instance, before calling the constructor (magic!)
we should use $onInit instead of constructor something like this

```
public $onInit() {
    this.message = 'worked!';
}
```